# How can I create a file that only my application can modify it?

Tags: c#, file

How can I create a file that only my application can modify? I need it because I have an app that creates a `.txt` file where user information is stored and I don't want the user to be able to modify it through File Explorer, but my App should be able to create it, modify it and delete it.

this is my code:

```
        public void Write(List<Queue> Queue)
        {
          try
          {
            CreateFile();
            using (FileStream Stream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Stream))
                {
                    string Data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Queue);
                    file.Write(Data);
                    file.Flush();
                    file.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.GetInstance().Write(ex.Message);
        }



public void CreateFile()
    {
        if (!FileExist)
        {
            File.Create(Path).Close();
        }
    }

    public List<Queue> ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileExist)
            {
                using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(Path))
                {
                    string Data= file.ReadToEnd();
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Cola>>(Data);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (JsonException ex)
        {
            Log.GetInstance().Write(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.GetInstance().Write(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `I don't want the user can modify it on from File Explorer` - Why not? What does your app intend to store in the file? There is likely a better way to accomplish your goal but we have to know what the *actual* goal is.

Comment: short answer: **you can't**. long answer: you can make it harder for the user, but you won't ever(!) be able to prevent it, and it's not at all worth the effort.

Comment: There's literally no way for an application to create and maintain a file (or any other locally stored data) in a way that noone else can.

Comment: You can persist an in memory version of the file contents and periodically replace the file if it doesn't match what is in memory, but at that point what's the point of even having a physical file. This is what databases are for.

Comment: You could _encrypt_ the contents of the file, but the trick there is keeping the decryption key secret. You can make it _hard_ to get but not _impossible_.

Comment: If the application is a ASP.NET web service you can run this with an isolated account that has the only access right to that folder. But as other in prior comments wrote: There are other better solutions.

Comment: @Igor The information that my application stores are the applications that the user has been using along with their time of use to later register them in the database

Comment: @LuisGarcia Is there a reason why that information can't be persisted to the DB at the point of capture and can only be done later?

Comment: @Saggio it doesn't matter whether the information is in DB or not. DB is just a fancy file, nothing else. It won't provide any security if it is used locally with locally stored keys.

Comment: @Igor if the app are not be able to connect to the database it stores the information in a file

Comment: That does not sound like anything that is sensitive (something you need to hide away from a determined user). I would not worry about it but if you needed to obscure it you could encrypt the content of the file.

Comment: @LuisGarcia why would an app have trouble connecting to database? Or rather connecting to a server that connects to a database?

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt the file to prevent tampering. Well, at least any tampering will corrupt the file.

The CLR has a mechanism to encrypt data to a specific user without having to generate and store a key separately. This uses the [`ProtectedData.Protect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.protect?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) and  [`ProtectedData.Unprotect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.unprotect?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) mechanism in `System.Security.Cryptography`.

Here is a test program. Run it one, select 1 to store data, type in something secret then quit. Run it a second time, select 2 to read data and the secret text will appear.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to 1. store data, 2. read data or 0. exit ?");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input.Length == 0 || input[0] == '0') break;

            if (input[0] == '1')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type in a very secret message to store:");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                var text = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                if (text.Length > 0)
                {
                    WriteToFile(text);
                }
            }

            if (input[0] == '2')
            {
                if (ReadFromFile(out string text))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const string filename = "data.enc";

    static bool WriteToFile(string text)
    {
        var fn = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), filename);
        var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
        try
        {
            var cipher = ProtectedData.Protect(data, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            File.WriteAllBytes(fn, cipher);
            Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted {data.Length} bytes in {fn}.");
            return true;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error encoding data: ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error creating file: ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return false;
    }

    static bool ReadFromFile(out string text)
    {
        var fn = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), filename);
        try
        {
            var cipher = File.ReadAllBytes(fn);
            var data = ProtectedData.Unprotect(cipher, null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
            text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted {data.Length} bytes from {fn}.");
            return true;

        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error decoding data: ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error reading file: ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        text = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: scr1]

and the contents of `data.enc` are completely encryted:

[image: scr2]

Comment: A more elaborate version of the above https://www.syncfusion.com/succinctly-free-ebooks/cryptography-in-net-succinctly/cryptographic-key-containers

Answer (score 1):

You cannot as far as I know. Users and/or administrators will have access to that file either way. You can, however, detect modification by hashing the file and comparing the hash with the file

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a file that only my application can modify it?

You can't. Simple as that.

The thing is that administrators can access all files. And the user your running your app with. And hackers of course. ;) Typically you would just store application files in some well established locations, e.g. it is a de facto standard to put app files in `/var/lib/myapp` in unix systems. Of course other users will still be able to access those files, but that way you at least lower accidental modifications risk. However this also means that **you should never store sensitive data locally**.

Encryption is not really an option, because you have to store the encryption key somewhere, which just moves the pile from one place to another. It does make read/write a bit harder, but it doesn't really solve the issue. Unless you don't store the key anywhere, e.g. you manually provide it on application start or even better during runtime and you ensure it doesn't live too long. Depending on your usecase this may be a valid option.

Modification detection, i.e. hashing the file, has exactly the same issue: you have to store the hash somewhere. You only force the malicious user to modify two locations instead of one.

Note that using a database engine locally won't help at all. At the end of the day a database is just a fancy file, and you still need to store access keys somewhere.

All in all: if you are storing a non-sensitive data, then put it in application data folder and don't worry about it.

Comment: You don't have to store the credentials yourself. Use a cryptographic store to keep the keys of compression.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I don't see how cryptographic store solves that problem. If an app can access that store, then a malicious user can access it outside of the app. You just moved the pile elsewhere. You increased obfuscation, yes, but you didn't increase security at all.

Comment: The key is based on the current user. So a 3rd party with access to the app would need to impersonate the author credentials.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou or simply be that user. Which sounds to me like the case OP describes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your application should do, but the way to achieve this would be to create a new user or group on the computer and run your application as that user. You can then use [SetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8) to make it so that the user or group as read/write permissions and everyone else has read permissions. This should actually be a Windows service rather then an application.